# Joke generator with random jokes not working

Tags: python

I'm currently making myself a script on python that will pick jokes and display them to the user. I need to use a random picker to select one of the jokes on the list and display it. I have been trying this for a long time and can't seem to get it to work. Please help!

E.G:

```
import random

random.choice joke
print random joke
^^^^
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your list? Please post your code so far.

Comment: Put all the jokes in a list and use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to select one.

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a precise specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: This looks more like a joke than a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a list of jokes. Let's imagine this is called jokeList. Start with

```
from random import randint
```

and then our program might look a little like this:

```
randChoice = randint(0, len(jokeList)-1)
joke = jokeList[randChoice]
print(joke)
```

Comment: I have a joke machine that will print multiple lines to make it look like a box, this is where the problem comes because i don't know how to declare a variable with multiple lines of text. (I am very new to python :P)

Comment: When you are writing strings, putting in a \n makes it return to the next line down. This should allow you to span multiple lines with a single string variable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it out.

Comment: Do i put \n in or out of the brackets?

Comment: It should be in a string if you want it to print to the next line. You can concatenate the String "\n" to your joke strings using a +

Comment: It seems when I add \n to it it leaves gaps inbetween all of my text :I

Comment: Print statements in python already end the line, that's just if you want more lines skpped.